# Прогнозирование да/нет

Tags: python, нейронные-сети

Есть база данных (дата/пользователь/товар), заказы пользователей.

Необходимо предсказать какие товары клиенты закажут в следующий раз. На выходе должна появиться колонка со значениями 0 или 1 (да/нет).

Проблема в том, что изначально Ytrain нет, не смогу обучить нейронку.

Если создам колонку и заполню единицами т.к. товары заказаны, то и нейронка на выходе мне выдаст тоже единицы.

Думал может сгруппировать по пользователям и взять все товары, тогда можно будет заполнить 0 и 1, что человек заказывал и попробовать обучить, но кажется это тоже не выгорит. Да и база увеличивается в разы, а она и так не маленькая. Если обучать по одному пользователю, а предиктить всех остальных, будет не объективно.

Есть ли какие-то решения данной задачи?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, нужно брать медиану как предиктор.

Comment: Вы всё правильно написали же, действительно для обучения нужна полная выборка всех товаров и всех клиентов с 0 и 1 и по ней учить. Возможно не стоит хранить модель для обучения в той базе, просто сделайте нужный запрос (сохраните запрос где-нибудь) с 0 и 1 и затем выгрузите его, этого будет достаточно для обучения, а если клиентов и продуктов станет больше снова выполните весь процесс для переобучения

Comment: Будут же не только 1, ведь не все клиенты купили все товары. Нужно сделать и записи для не купленных клиентами товаров, там таргет будет 0. Но в целом задача не такая простая. Что за товары вообще? Если это продукты, то да - в следующий раз скорее всего купят то, что и до этого часто покупали. А если это техника, электроника и т.д., то в ближайшие много лет этот же человек вряд ли купит такой же товар.